# Паттерн Builder

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Во описании шаблона на Вики в классе Builder используются заранее созданные методы buildXXX() для построения разных объектов с одинаковыми значениями полей. Но если каждый раз нужно создавать поля с разными значениями, логично передавать значения как параметры.
Вопрос, позволяет ли паттерн передачу значений полей в качестве параметров, если нет, то как наиболее правильно поступать в таких случаях?  Особенно при большом числе требуемых параметров.

Comment: Собственно сама суть Bulder'а в том и состоит, чтоб строить объект по кускам

Comment: методы в вики названы не очень удачно. `buildXXX` - это сеттеры частей Строителя. а сам каноничный метод `build` в  этом случае представлен методом `getPizza`. Кстати, второй пример там же более привычен.

Comment: Ну да, названия методов немного путают.  Но я понял из ответа rjhdby , что нет ничего, что препятствует передачи в них параметров?

Comment: Просто посмотрите второй пример. Конечно можно.

Comment: На сколько я видел билдер обычно используется для построения сложных обьектов поэтапно.
На пример

`new SomeObjectBuilder().
withName("").
withCount("").
build();
`

Возможно у этого билдера есть дюжина таких "with" методов. Но мы вызываем только те что нам нужны. А билд может проверить все ли необходимые значения заданы и бросить ошибку если не все. 
Без билдера пришлось бы сделать кучу разных конструкторов что бы моч задать разное сочитание параметров и получать ошибку при необходимости.